# control a checkbox via an IMG using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to control the checked state of a checkbox when a user clicks on an image with the class of ".latinAmerica" within the page. Each click should check/uncheck it each time.

I've tried a ton of different methods but I can't find anything suitable for checkboxes.

EG:

```
$('.latinAmerica').click(function () {  
    if($('input:checkbox[name=theName]:nth(0)').is(':checked')) {
        $('input:checkbox[name=theName]:nth(0)').attr('checked',true);
    } else {
        $('input:checkbox[name=theName]:nth(0)').attr('checked',false);
    }   
});
```

or

```
$('.latinAmerica').click(function () {  
    $("input:checkbox[name=theName]:nth(0)").prop("checked", true);
});
```

I did get this method working with radio buttons:

```
$('.latinAmerica').click(function () {  
    $('input:checkbox[name=theName]:nth(0)').attr('checked',true);
});
```

But no luck with checkboxes.

What am I doing wrong :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $(".latinamerica").click(function() {
        var cb = $("input[name='theName']");
        if(cb.is(":checked")) {
            cb.prop("checked", "");
        } else {
            cb.prop("checked", "checked");
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JFDxj/

Answer (score 1):

The if condition is wrong so it must not doing anything i.e. checkedbox is checked when it is already checked and unchecked when it is already unchecked.

```
$('.latinAmerica').click(function () {  
    if($('input:checkbox[name=theName]:nth(0)').is(':checked')) {
        $('input:checkbox[name=theName]:nth(0)').attr('checked',false);
    } else {
        $('input:checkbox[name=theName]:nth(0)').attr('checked',true);
    }   
});
```